# Vim keyboard remap on Snow Leopard (MacOs 10.6)

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, vim, keyboard-layout

I want to have my external keyboard's <kbd>HOME</kbd>, <kbd>END</kbd>, <kbd>PAGEDOWN</kbd> and <kbd>PAGEUP</kbd> working on Leopard's Terminal. So that I changed  in Terminal > File > Preferences:

```
Home: \033[H  
End: \033[F  
PageUp: \033[5~  
PageDown: \033[6~
```

It works 100% in command line - but it doesn't work while editing files in VIM.
Is there any possibility of remapping VIM keyboard in order to have these keys working?

Regards

Comment: Should be SuperUser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, according to the question, you already know the mappings, then it's easy..

```
Home: \033[H  
End: \033[F  
PageUp: \033[5~  
PageDown: \033[6~
```

Just edit ~/.vimrc and add:

```
map <Esc>[H <Home>
imap <Esc>[H <Home>
map <Esc>[F <End>
imap <Esc>[F <End>
map <Esc>[5~ <PageUp>
imap <Esc>[5~ <PageUp>
map <Esc>[6~ <PageDown>
imap <Esc>[6~ <PageDown>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:imap <C-k><Home> <Home>
:map <C-k><Home> <Home>
```

-- actually hitting control-k and your home key for both, to enter what vim reads from your home key, then typing the second `<Home>`.  And so on for the other bindings.  See `:help :map` and `:help <>`.

Comment: How can I permanently save such modifications in my vi configuration?

Comment: In my case, I prefer hitting control-v instead of control-k .

Comment: C-v is what I'm used to, and tried, but gvim binds it differently on windows.  C-k is advertised to do the same for 'special keys'.

Answer (score 1):

I have permanently solved it.

In my case, I have mapped it in vim:

```
:imap <C-v><Home> <Home>
:map <C-v><Home> <Home>
```

-- actually hitting control-v and your home key for both, to enter what vim reads from my home key, then typing the second .

It works, but it lasts only for the current session.
So, I just type the following command, followed by <**Enter**>

```
:map
```

Then I get the mappings

```
<Esc>[H <Home>
```

Now, I just add it to my ~/.vimrc file:

```
map <Esc>[H <Home>
imap <Esc>[H <Home>
```

now it is remapped to all vim sessions of my user.

Comment: reference: http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/map.html